# Why can't IronPython be installed with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: ironpython, visual-studio-2010

IronPython has been out for a while now, so when I installed Visual Studio 2010 RC1 "Ultimate" this morning I was surprised to find that it couldn't be selected from the installer. Instead, one still has to go out to Codeplex. Does anybody know why it hasn't been included?

Comment: I love IP, but if they want it to kick off they need it to be a first class langauge within VS. Just look at F#. You can't say that would be half as popluar if it wasn't for VS support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have picked up from the IP mailing list...

Ironpython is on a different release cycle to Visual Studio and developed by a separate team. The MS G.O. team development process is far more responsive and agile than a 2 year release cycle. Given the changing nature of CPython (+other implementations) with frequent releases and the continuing need to improve compatibility with third party libraries (large code base), it makes sense to keep it apart.

Visual Studio support is currently in a restricted developer preview. As it is an add-in, this too will be free of a 2 year cycle and hopefully be more frequently improved.

Answer (score 3):

They accept user submitted code, because of this there are patent issues and infringing code possibilities, John Lam talked about this in a podcast with dotnetrocks. What would happen if this code violated something? Microsoft would have to take Visual Studio off the shelves until they fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Asking MS at PyCon 2009, they were investigating IPy for VS 'next plus 1' - which hasn't been released yet.

For VS2010, you can use IronPython Tools for Visual Studio 2010 - www.ironpython.net.

Answer (score -1):

May be because it is not an "official" language?

Comment: Wrong. Microsoft supports it now.