# Is there a way to add Python to Visual Studio 2010 Express (the free version)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Seems like Python can be easily integrated in Visual Studio 2010, I found various articles and the relative plugin needed.

I doesn't work for my VS 2010 Express though. I doubt it only works for the commercial version.

Is there some other way to enable the Python language in VS 2010 Express?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't IronPython be installed with Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419662/why-cant-ironpython-be-installed-with-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: @Paul: in that question it's being asked if and why Python it's not  included in VS. I'm asking for a plugin to enable it, since I already think it's not present in VS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Express doesn't allow you to install extensions like IronPython Tools (which I assume you're talking about?).

Luckily according to [this](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2010-May/012760.html) they have a standalone variant that works with the VS shell, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1366). Haven't used it myself because thanks to my academic license I get the newest VS for free (very nice from MS that) ;)

Answer (score 1):

[CodePlex](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation) offers a quick and easy implementation for installing python tools for visual studios.